# jquery-in-place-editor pre post hooks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery

I'm using [jquery edit in place](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-in-place-editor/) lib and I'm having a problem when trying to use a class selector to select multiple editable items.

I'm calling editInPlace on an array of elements so I don't have to repeat that call for each editable item.

What I can't figure out is how to append the item id to the url.  I'm using rails so I need a url like `tags/10`

Do you know how to dynamically alter the url or params for each editable item?  I tried using the callback param but that cancels the ajax request.

html:

```
<li class="tag" id="tag_1">bright light</li>
<li class="tag" id="tag_2">soft light</li>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.tag').editInPlace({
  url:"/tags/" // NEED TO ADD THE ASSET ID TO THE URL example /tags/10
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/), like this:

```
$('.tag').each(function() {
  $(this).editInPlace({
    url:"/tags/" + this.id.replace('tag_','')
  });
});
```

This just takes the ID and removes the `tag_` portion via [`.replace()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) before appending it.

Comment: Why not just do:

 `$('.tag').editInPlace({
  url:"/tags/" + $(this).id.replace('tag_','');
});`

??

Comment: I am really sorry about typing in `$(this).id` (i just copy/paste the code). It should have been `$(this).attr(id)`. Also, i thought jQuery dealt with having `this` always refer to the parent function rather than the window/document. Anyways, i guess your are probably right about the second part too. Should try it out. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @Shripad - You're correct that it *usually* refers to the parent function...and it does here as well, the parent function is the `document.ready` handler.  The important thing is that just calling `.plugin(option)` doesn't create a closure, you're still *in* that parent function...whereas `.each()` does create a closure, where `this` refers to the element you want :)

Comment: Awesome! That answered my question accurately. It had to do with closures!! Cool. Thanks for the info :)